# Proper way to use Ksoap2

Tags: android, ksoap2

I'm trying to connect my android application to a database.I used a webservice & ksoap2.
I tested my database connection with jdbc it works perfectly but when i try it in my application nothing happen and sometimes it bugs.I tried everything but i didn't found the solution.
Here is my code :

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    private final String NAMESPACE = "http://ws.userlogin.com";
    private final String METHOD_NAME = "authentication";
    private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://ws.userlogin.com/authentication";
    private final String URL = "http://192.168.1.3:8080/and-back/services/Login?wsdl";
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                loginAction();

            }
        });
    }

    private void loginAction(){
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        EditText userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_userName);
        String user_Name = userName.getText().toString();
        EditText userPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_password);
        String user_Password = userPassword.getText().toString();

      //Pass value for userName variable of the web service
        PropertyInfo unameProp =new PropertyInfo();
        unameProp.setName("userName");//Define the variable name in the web service method
        unameProp.setValue(user_Name);//set value for userName variable
        unameProp.setType(String.class);//Define the type of the variable
        request.addProperty(unameProp);//Pass properties to the variable

      //Pass value for Password variable of the web service
        PropertyInfo passwordProp =new PropertyInfo();
        passwordProp.setName("password");
        passwordProp.setValue(user_Password);
        passwordProp.setType(String.class);
        //request.addProperty(passwordProp);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try{
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
               SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();

               TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_status);
               result.setText(response.toString());

        }
        catch(Exception e){
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
       }


}
```

Comment: have you logged the request and the result?

Comment: PreparedStatement statement =  con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '"+userName+"'");
   ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
i tried the query as a java application it works

Comment: u should be usign asynctask for making soap request. can u post logcat

Comment: nothing is being show on the logcat,when i click on the login button the app stops & after a while it forces close it

Comment: check you logcat again.

Comment: ThrottleService Error reading data file

Comment: Is there any problem in the code written?